# Show end screen after collision detection

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skphysicsbody

I am trying to have a GameOverScene after there is a collision between my first sprite, a squirrel, and my second sprite, an acorn/nut. Right now, when the two sprites collide, the squirrel just falls of the screen. I want the squirrel to fall off the screen but an end screen to pop up. Here is what I have so far:

```
- (instancetype)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
    [self buildBackground];
    [self startScrolling];

    [self initializeStartGameLayer];
    [self initializeGameOverLayer];

    _firstPosition = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.817f,     self.frame.size.height * .40f);
    _squirrelSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"squirrel"];
    _squirrelSprite.position = _firstPosition;
    _atFirstPosition = YES;

    _squirrelSprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:10];
    _squirrelSprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = squirrelHitCategory;
    _squirrelSprite.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = nutHitCategory;
    _squirrelSprite.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =  nutHitCategory;

    _squirrelSprite.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

    [self addChild:_squirrelSprite];

    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:3.0];

    SKAction *createSpriteBlock = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        SKSpriteNode *lightnut = [SKSpriteNode     spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"lightnut.png"];
        BOOL heads = arc4random_uniform(100) < 50;
        lightnut.position = (heads)? CGPointMake(257,600) : CGPointMake(50,600);

        lightnut.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody     bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(200,160)];

        lightnut.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = nutHitCategory;
        lightnut.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = squirrelHitCategory;
        lightnut.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =  squirrelHitCategory;

        lightnut.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;

        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

        [self addChild: lightnut];

        SKAction *moveNodeUp = [SKAction moveByX:0.0 y:-700.0 duration:1.3];
        [lightnut runAction: moveNodeUp];
    }];

    SKAction *waitThenRunBlock = [SKAction sequence:@[wait,createSpriteBlock]];

    [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:waitThenRunBlock]];

}
return self;
}
```

I tried using the tutorial for making an end and start screen from this page: http://mytechspace.com/2014/02/tutorial-how-to-develop-flappy-bird-game-in-ios-using-spritekit-part2-of-2.html but neither my start or end screen was showing up (I'm not sure what was stopping it).

Here is my contact delegate method:

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{ 

SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

firstBody = contact.bodyA;
secondBody = contact.bodyB;

if(firstBody.categoryBitMask == squirrelHitCategory || secondBody.categoryBitMask == nutHitCategory)
{

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please post the contact delegate method, i.e. -didBeginContact: as well

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764620/start-screen-and-end-screen-after-collision-detection/26767436#26767436

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

    firstBody = contact.bodyA;
    secondBody = contact.bodyB;

    if(firstBody.categoryBitMask == squirrelHitCategory || secondBody.categoryBitMask == nutHitCategory)
    {
        [self gameOver];
    }
}

- (void)gameOver
{
    GameOverScene *gameOverScene = [GameOverScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
    [self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition:[SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionLeft duration:0.5]];
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! For some reason it keeps giving me the error "Use of undeclared identifier 'GameOverScene'" even when I thought I declared it, do you happen to know how to correctly declare it?

Comment: Yes I have a GameOverScene.m and GameOverScene.h, should I declare them in those?

Comment: And u should create navigation controller